# Need help to add values into a database

Tags: ios, sqlite

My Document is like this ...


**"When a work appears to be ahead of its time, it is only the time that is behind the work" –Jean Cocteau

"When a work lifts your spirits and inspires bold and noble thoughts in you, do not look for any other standard to judge by: the work is good, the product of a master craftsman" –Jean de la Bruyere

"When a writer talks about his work, he's talking about a love affair" –Alfred Kazin

"When love and skill work together, expect a masterpiece" –John Ruskin**

can anyone suggest me how i can bulk insert this types of values to database by recognizing them with " .

i really need some efficient method to do it because my document is around 10,000 pages and i have to add all this to database and invoke in ios application..

Thanks in advance..
I know i will get my answer only here :)

Comment: What type of document do you have (is it word document or any other?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: What is your background? Are you a programmer, which language do you use? I think you need some coding here.

Comment: Ya i m ios devloper i know sql php also.. i need just some hint how to do it.. i will try my best to implement it...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is possible for your docment and your situation, but what if you save this as text document and then parse it?

Parsing would be straightfoward - you should find first appearance of " and then you should fnd second appearance of ". Then get text between  first and second ", and put into database.

Comment: This only me also thinking but problem is i need some guidance how it is possible any tutorial or something which help me how it can be possible. thanks